# Automatically Deleting data from DynamoDB Table and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have started exploring `DynamoDB` and `S3` recently.

I went through the Developer Guide, I was curious that Is there any way to delete data from DynamoDB Table or S3 bucket based on some condition ?

The conditions here may be **time/space**.
Like I want to delete data from `DynamoDB/S3` after some time(say 200 days) or if it exceeds some limit like 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

For S3, it is possible to delete after a given time using [lifecyles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/LifecycleConfiguration.html). For DynamoDB, there is no such a rule.

For both, there is no direct way to clean based on the space taken.

In practice, it is possible to do it "quite easily" using [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/) and the S3 and DynamoDB events, but it requires to implement it: Each time a new entry is added (or each n times) notified by S3-/DynDB- events, compute the size and clean what should be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is DynamoDB TimeToLive feature. It is still in its Beta phase.

Your DDB table must have a TTL attribute storing the time stamp (in seconds).

> "TTL compares the current time in epoch time format to the time stored
>   in the designated TTL attribute of an item. If the epoch time value
>   stored in the attribute is less than the current time, the item is
>   marked as expired and subsequently deleted."

More details can be found in [DDB docs](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-preview-ttl/time-to-live-ttl.html)